# Inject Custom Module into angular app

Tags: angularjs

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var appName = "renameMe";

var fooModule = angular.module("foo", []);

var app = angular.module(appName, ["foo"]);
//var app = angular.module(appName, ["ui.router"]);

app.config(["foo", function (foo) {

}]);



angular.element(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, [appName]);
});
</script>
```

I cannot figure out how to fix my code from getting the below error. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

My End game is to have a standalone module injected into 
`app.config(["foo", 'function(foo){}]);`
So I can run some custom code

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Unknown provider: foo

Comment: trouble on this line `app.config(["foo", function (foo) {` you are injecting the module name as if it was a provider (service, factory, value, etc); and it's not, unless you have a provider named `foo` into the `foo` module, remove the injection.

Comment: If I remove the injection how do I access it?

Comment: You don't "access" the module, but it's providers, your module carry the controllers, services, directives, etc. Those are the ones you have to "access" as long you use it as a dependency module on your app module declaration `var app = angular.module(appName, ["foo"]);`

Comment: Because there is no 'foo' service. There is 'foo' module. Module !== service. Not even !=.

Comment: Cool, thank you. That fixed it. If you put this in an answer i will upvote and mark as answer

Comment: Sure, you're welcome.

Comment: I refuse my self, you should delete the question since the topic is pretty basic and must've been answered before (and also in the docs) and don't seem to be a question that might help others. But it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` module is already included to `renameMe` module with

```
var app = angular.module(appName, ["foo"]);
```

While

```
app.config(["foo", function (foo) {...}]);
```

expects that there will be `foo` service (more specifically, `constant` service). If there is none, `$injector:unpr` error is triggered.

If there is supposed to be no `foo` service, it should be just

```
app.config(function () {...});
```